# ASP.NET MVC 4 pass DB data back to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a View that accepts a name, does a lookup, and spits back a recordset to the page.

### The Model:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("FavouriteMovie")]
    public string FavouriteMovie { get; set; }
}
```

### The View:

```
 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@model MVCDatabaseFormTest.Models.User


MainForm


@Html.BeginForm();

This is the form
@Html.Label("Enter search for first name:");

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName);

<input type="submit" value="Search" name="FormCollector1.PostBackButton" id="Search" />

<br />

Display a title found:

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName);<br/>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName);<br/>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FavouriteMovie);<br/>
```

---

The Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(User user1)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=cl02db01.cluster01.thindata.net; Initial Catalog=dev_backupDatabase_v3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ProductionMonitoringDashboard;Password=f3sf3sdf33;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

        string info = user1.FirstName; // check value

        User u = new User();

        List<User> data = new List<User>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select id,firstname,lastname,movie from _jterhofstede_TestMVC (nolock) where firstname like '%" + info + "%'", conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    u.ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    u.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    u.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    u.FavouriteMovie = reader["movie"].ToString();
                    data.Add(u);

                }
            }


        }

        return View(u);
```

---

The Results:

The code accepts a first name, and finds the results in the db table, and by checking with the debugger, it is being loaded successfully into the variable u, and I am passing it back to the view.

However, the view does not display the results. I would actually ideally like to write the records out to the page (sort of like a GridView, but simpler).  I must be missing something simple but I cannot identify what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually displaying the returned data.  Your View only has labels for the fields, not the fields themselves.

You need something like:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName): @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)<br/>
```

By the way, you don't put semicolons after razor statements in most casts (only when in code blocks)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I knew it was a simple concept.  I'm very new to MVC, so I really appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of returning one object at the end of your controller to the view you should pass the entire list.
so instead of

```
return View(u);
```

you would use

```
return View(data);
```

Then in your view, at the top, accept the model as a List.
so instead of

```
@model MVCDatabaseFormTest.Models.User
```

use something like

```
@model List<MVCDatabaseFormTest.Models.User>
```

Also,
You declared your single object outside the loop, re-writing it every time you add it to the list. So you would end with a list that has the same object many times.
Instead, you need to instantiate a new one in each loop.
You need to comment out your first new outside your while loop and then 
you need something like this:

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           User u = new User();
            u.ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            u.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
            u.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
            u.FavouriteMovie = reader["movie"].ToString();
            data.Add(u);
        }
```